# Retrieving CRM OptionSet field using Simple.odata.client library

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, simple.odata.client

Can anyone provide the way to use it with `Simple.Odata.Client` library. I am using it as follows i.e.

```
string url = "EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes(LogicalName='new_country')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata? $select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet($select=Options)";

var countrylist = await client .FindEntriesAsync(url);
```

Following error is coming up i.e. The context URL

> 'http://api/data/v8.2/$metadata#EntityDefinitions('contact')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata(LogicalName,OptionSet,GlobalOptionSet,OptionSet(Options))/$entity'
>   is invalid.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?
Thanks!